# Link in the modal navigates to a div on landing page but returns back on anchor tag after being dismiss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anchor tag in second section opens a modal, there is a link in modal text which when clicked, should close the modal and naviagtes to first section on the same page.
    It is navigating to first section closes the modal and returns to the second section immediately.
    How can I keep it on first section.

```js
$('#anchor').click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');            
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

This is my modal

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            
 <a id="anchor" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#first">Click here</a> to continue
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="first">

</section>

<section id="second">
  <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">It opens modal
     </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Since I can't run the snippet here on SO I can't test it. What framework/library are you using? Maybe try to add `return true;` at the end of the function that closes the modal.

Comment: @StuntHacks MVC .Net and yes I tried adding return true; at the end of the function but still no success.